# ScrollRect extremely choppy movement

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas, scroll

I have a GameObject named PickupPanel with with a ScrollRect component, the GameObject has two buttons as children:

[image]

The button GameObjects look like this:
[image]

When scrolling the buttons the movement of the scroll is extremely choppy:

[image]

What could be causing this? Has anyone had any similar experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Unity3D documentation:

> ScrollRect.content
>
> The content that can be scrolled. **It should be a child of the
>   GameObject with ScrollRect on it.**

You have set the content to the same object as ScrollRect.

Check how the ScrollView is set up when you create it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, that is probably the issue. Thank you

Comment: Run into this issue especially on mobile, all you have to do is set Application.targetFrameRate to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Do you test with a default scrollrect?

Comment: I have tested with the default scrollrect aswell yes